# bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: bash, scripts, wget

I am trying to download flareget download manager via wget
I get error

```
wget  http://www.flareget.com/files/flareget/debs/amd64/flareget_2.3-24_amd64(stable)_deb.tar.gz
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Why is that error coming and what is the solution for that?

Comment: I received the same error while attempting to unzip a file that was password protected. The password had a parenthesis in it. I ended up having to use both double and single quotes to avoid the error. Example:

`mypass="'HWNevtQW9o2s)f'"`

`unzip -P $mypass myfile`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should use single quotes `'` or double quotes `"` around the URL in this case (and in general):

```
wget  'http://www.flareget.com/files/flareget/debs/amd64/flareget_2.3-24_amd64(stable)_deb.tar.gz'
```

From now, you should use this method in general when you use a string which contain parentheses as argument in a command. That is because parentheses are used for grouping by the shell such that they are not communicated in any way to a command. So, the bash shell will give you a syntax error:

```
$ echo some (parentheses)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
$ echo 'some (parentheses)'
some (parentheses)
```

Comment: Thank you ! This is work for me!

Answer (score 14):

It's because of the brackets. You need to escape them like this:

```
wget  http://www.flareget.com/files/flareget/debs/amd64/flareget_2.3-24_amd64\(stable\)_deb.tar.gz
```

Now it should work.

Comment: its worked but need permanent solution

Comment: @matinict just wrap the URL in double quotes and don't bother with the backslash. That's my permanent good practice.

Answer (score 12):

Mine had nothing to do with un-escaped brackets and everything to do with an alias already being defined with the same name as the function.

Alias in one file:

```
alias foo="echo do something"
```

Function in another:

```
foo() {
    # Do something else
}
```

Both of these files were sourced by my `~/.bashrc`, giving me the unhelpful error message:

```
syntax error near unexpected token (
```

Comment: This one was my case. Also in my case even sourcing empty file didn't delete aliases created. So had to manually call unalias <aliasName>. Only after that sourcing file worked for me.

Comment: Similar behavior. The alias previously created doesn't go away. Either unalias it or open a new terminal for the change to show up.